# How to view and set option congigurable value for add to cart programmatically in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I want to retrieve ordered items  and then add to cart by code. 
I create a collection and I also got the ordered items and I print it. This as example of an item,

```
        [item_id] => 535
        [order_id] => 99
        [parent_item_id] => 
        [quote_item_id] => 1187
        [store_id] => 1
        [product_id] => 1541
        [product_type] => configurable
        [product_options] => a:6:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:6:{s:4:"uenc";s:108:"aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9zbWFycnRob21lcy9pbmRleC5waHAvZGVtby1wcm9kdWN0LWNvbmZpZy0xNTYzLmh0bWw_b3B0aW9ucz1jYXJ0";s:7:"product";s:4:"1541";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:15:"super_attribute";a:1:{i:136;s:2:"34";}s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:6:"isAjax";s:1:"1";}s:15:"attributes_info";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Pack Size";s:5:"value";s:6:"150 gm";}}s:11:"simple_name";s:31:"Haldiram's   All In One 150 gm ";s:10:"simple_sku";s:10:"SH_SNAC_10";s:20:"product_calculations";i:1;s:13:"shipment_type";i:0;}
        [weight] => 150.0000
        [is_virtual] => 0
        [sku] => SH_SNAC_10
```

Now I want to add this product to cart with the specified product option. 
Example -
A product type is configurable and its option size are **S, M, L**. I Ordered a size ( **S**). Now its should be shows Selected size (e.g **S**) and also add to cart with selected Size.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
public function _getProductList($orders) {
   $itm = 0;
   $productList = array();
   foreach($orders as $order){
     $order_id = $order['entity_id'];
     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
     $items = $order->getAllItems();
     foreach($items as $item) { 
       echo '<pre>'; print_r(); echo '</pre>';
       $productList[$itm]['product_id'] = $item->getProductId();
       $productList[$itm]['product_options'] = $item->getProductOptions();
       $itm = $itm + 1;
     }
  }
  return $productList;
}
```

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: What are you trying to do?
AFAIK, ordered products should be displayed in the customer's cart automatically. Isn't so?

Comment: I trying to custom collection of all complete ordered and there items of a log in customer and then show all product items(product type may be simple or configurable) of all orders, then I want to move all products simultaneously to cart through Action.

Comment: Now I understand you even less. You want to add all products from past orders to the current user's cart? Why?

Comment: I want to show all past products into ordered of a customer not order-wise. And customer can reorder here.